# if $\alpha$ is an ordinal is it true that ${\aleph _{\alpha +1}}^{\aleph _{\alpha}}=\aleph _{\alpha +1}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If we denote the following cardinals: $\beta _0=\aleph _0$,  $\beta _k=2^{\beta _{k-1}}$
then I know that ${\beta _{k+1}}^{\beta _k}=\beta _{k+1}$

but, is it true that for some ordinal $\alpha$,
 ${\aleph _{\alpha+1}}^{\aleph _{\alpha}}={\aleph _{\alpha+1}}$?

I really don't know how to approach this.

Comment: Note that the usual notation for your $\beta_k$ is $\beth_k$ which is typed as `$\beth_k$`.

Comment: @HenningMakholm sorry, I'm not familiar with this notation

Comment: x @dorsh: Now you are. For finite $k$ it works _exactly_ like what you have defined there, just with the letter $\beth$ instead of $\beta$. It is then generalized to limit ordinal subscripts by taking upper bounds just like the $\aleph$ sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not necessarily true. In particular, whenever the continuum hypothesis fails so we have $\aleph_1 < 2^{\aleph_0}$, it will still be the case that
$$ \aleph_1^{\aleph_0} \ge 2^{\aleph_0} $$
by simple inclusion.

---

This doesn't answer whether it is consistent with ZFC that $\aleph_{\alpha+1}{}^{\aleph_\alpha} \ne \aleph_{\alpha+1}$ for *all* $\alpha$. However, that would follow (by the above argument) if it is consistent that $2^\kappa>\kappa^+$ for all infinite cardinals $\kappa$, which [Wikipedia asserts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis#The_generalized_continuum_hypothesis) has been proved by Foreman and Woodin, under certain large-cardinal assumptions.